# How to see the tables created on oracle cloud

Tags: oracle, dbaas, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I am new to DBaaS, I created a new oracle cloud account and instantiated a DB.
I am connecting to the DB using `SQL developer` and created a new table by logging in as `sys` user.

How do I see the newly created table on oracle cloud using web console?
I can see the data that I have added into the newly created table using `SQL Developer`, but is there any way or does oracle provides any web-console to see the data using a browser?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: First of all - DO NOT use sys user to crete objects in the same schema! This user is responsible for all kinds of things, which keeps your DB running etc. For more information see this: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMQS/GUID-CF1CD853-AF15-41EC-BC80-61918C73FDB5.htm#ADMQS12003

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible using OEM Cloud Control. To view data, navigate to database homepage/summary. From the top menu, navigate to

```
Schema -> Database Objects -> Tables.
```

[image]

Fill in the desired schema and click "Go". This will populate a list of the tables within the schema. Click on the table name to view the table.

Once at the View Table page, select "View Data" from the Actions menu and click "Go". This will return the top 25 rows from the selected table. If there are more than 2000 rows, you will be given the option to select specific columns and add a where clause.

Comment: I have Oracle 12.1.0.2.0 on the cloud, and I opened the Oracle Enterprise Manager, I don't see any schema or database objects in the Oracle Enterprise Manager wizard.

Comment: The database in question must be added as a target in OEM first - you cannot use OEM to view data in a database that has not been added as a target. To add the database as a target, navigate to  Setup -> Add Target at the top right (next to account name.) Once the database is added, navigate to Targets -> Databases at the top left of the page, select the database from the list of targets, then follow these instructions.

More info on adding the database as a target can be found here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24628_01/install.121/e22624/install_agent.htm#EMBSC181